# truested but still error The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address

Tags: internet-explorer-9, certificate, ssl-certificate

we have an intranet website. it is self-signed. i added the certificate to trusted zone. add the site to trusted site and intranet site, but still get this error.

```
The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address.
Security certificate problems may indicate an attempt to fool you or intercept any data you send to the server.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is users connect to server by ip and not the address.bcs site signed by previous admin i didn't know which address the certificate was issued for. so checked the cert address

start>certmgr.msc
found the certificate
in detail tab, found subject property, in the attributes, the CN is showing the address of website:

[image]

so i added the address of website into the dns and everything get fine.so users will need to connect to the website by "http:///" not "http://"
**(if the certificate issued for contoso.com but users access to the site by ip this error will be shown)